# javax.jms.Message from IBM MQ has "null" JMSDestination

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, java-ee-7

When consuming a javax.jms.Message from IBM MQ I want to log the message id and destination it came from like this:

```
Received [ID:...] from [...]
```

For some messages this works fine and looks like this:

```
Received [ID:414d5120465030303030374920202020a948b66401d61440] from [queue://MYQMGR/MYQ]
```

But for some other queues on the same queue manager Message.getJMSDestination() returns null, and I get this:

```
Received [ID:414d512053415a324d5131452020202063c3b3fc9c229718] from [null]
```

- What is the reason for this?
- What can I do to fix it?

Details about my context:

- JEE7, Java 8
- MDB listens to MQ queue (onMessage(javax.jms.Message))

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using logic akin to

```
        try {
            Destination jmsDestination = message.getJMSDestination();
            if (jmsDestination != null) {
                q = ((Queue) jmsDestination).getQueueName();
                System.out.println(formatTime() + " JMS message received by from queue: " + q);
            } else {
                System.out.println(formatTime() + " MQ message received");
            }
        } catch (JMSRuntimeException | JMSException e) {
            msgErr = " ERROR: JMS error getting destination: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
            throw new RuntimeException(msgErr, e);
        }
```

In which case a null destination indicates that the message didn't come from a JMS application. IE. if the sender application was a Node.js making use of the MQI API then you would expect to see JMSDestination as null.

Comment: Yes indeed I use such a logic. Does that mean my MDB has no chance to report from which queue the message came from? Can I instruct MQ to add that JMS destination to messages?